# Web API Content into a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, api

Is it possible to post data retrieved via a Web API into a SharePoint list?  my scenario is that I want to pull some data from a third product via its WEB API and post it if possible into a SharePoint Online calendar.  As I've not done this before, I'm not sure what my options, if any, are.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible. Your question does not indicate what approach you are using to develop your program so I will keep it more general. You should take a look at the SharePoint REST service info here [Get to know Sharepoint REST Service](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/apis/rest/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service)

Other than that, Danny is correct that authentication is the other issue to consider.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has a REST API just like any other

The main issue is authentication,
so it depends on whether you are already logged in

If not then you need to authorize with O365 and push your content

If you are logged in you only need to read your Web API and use the SharePoint REST API to write the data.. search for REST and SharePoint

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for this.  I'm quite new to programming so will have to break this down into steps.   I'm guessing the retrieval part would be authentication into the app and then retrieving the information.  Second stage is to post the data to a SharePoint list?

Comment: Both ways they are APIs you talk to. All Office365 APIs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396